# Shared Empty Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have utility class like this:

```
public class IntArrays
{
    public static final int[] EMPTY = new int[0];

    public static int[] empty() { return EMPTY; }

    // ...
}
```

Is it safe to distribute and re-use such a shared array with length `0`, or should I get rid of the field and replace the method with

```
public static int[] empty() { return new int[0]; }
```

Comment: If you return a new array each time, the array will be a different one (`new`), else this will be the same each time, regardless of it being still empty, or being now filled with values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you have one array which is actually shared.

In the second example, you are creating an array each time, so it's not actually shared.

> Is it save to distribute and re-use such a shared array with length 0

So only the first example, achieves this.

Even though an `new int[0]` is immutable, it has a lock.  When you share a lock it has a different behaviour to creating an object each time. i.e. it has some state even if it is indirect.

If you don't want to expose the field `EMPTY` you could make it private.